Save in Notepad++ resets file execution flag in WSL
Every time I save my bash scripts in notepad++ from within Windows the executable flag (file mode bit - chmod +x ...) in wsl (v2) is removed.
My scripts reside outside of wsl directory structure and I access them via /mnt/c/.../myscript.sh
This happens regardless of starting notepad++ from within WSL or directly in Windows.
Any idea on how I can keep the executable flag across saving?
As a workaround I currently prefix them with bash scriptname, which is cumbersome.

I wonder whether this would be better if asked on the Notepad++ forum. If you do get an answer there then please add an answer here with full details (and link to the off site information).

The question appears to have been asked on the Notepad++ forum, see here.
